# Weaviate javascript client '.withAsk' returning 'undefined', what am I missing?

Tags: typescript, weaviate

I've populated a Weaviate Cloud Cluster by following the steps in the [quick start manual](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/quickstart).

I have imported data and the client connection works.

Then for the `ask` function, I've implemented the following:

```js
export async function question(collection: Collections, question: string) {
  await client.graphql
    .get()
    .withClassName(collection)
    .withAsk({ question })
    .withFields('memberName _additional { answer { hasAnswer property result startPosition endPosition } }')
    .withLimit(5)
    .do()
}

question(Collections.TeamMember, 'Who has painting as a hobby?')
  .then((result) => { console.log(result) });
```

This will return `undefined`. I was expecting it to return `Sarah Mitchell`.

---

### Additional info:

#### Schema

I have manually created a schema so that `qna-openai` could be added to the `moduleConfig` as [described here](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/modules/reader-generator-modules/qna-openai):

```js
export async function addClassToSchema(classObject: object) {
  const res = await client.schema.classCreator().withClass(classObject).do();
}
```

The class object:

```json
{
  "class": "TeamMember",
  "vectorizer": "text2vec-openai",
  "moduleConfig": {
    "text2vec-openai": {},
    "qna-openai": {
      "model": "text-davinci-002",
      "maxTokens": 16,
      "temperature": 0.0,
      "topP": 1,
      "frequencyPenalty": 0.0,
      "presencePenalty": 0.0
    }
  },
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "teamName",
      "dataType": ["text"]
    },
    {
      "name": "memberName",
      "dataType": ["text"]
    },
    {
      "name": "jobDescription",
      "dataType": ["text"]
    },
    {
      "name": "responsibilities",
      "dataType": ["text"]
    },
    {
      "name": "education",
      "dataType": ["text"]
    },
    {
      "name": "hobbies",
      "dataType": ["text"]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I GET https://test-cluster-name.weaviate.network/v1/schema I get the following response:

```json
{
    "classes": [
        {
            "class": "TeamMember",
            "invertedIndexConfig": {
                "bm25": {
                    "b": 0.75,
                    "k1": 1.2
                },
                "cleanupIntervalSeconds": 60,
                "stopwords": {
                    "additions": null,
                    "preset": "en",
                    "removals": null
                }
            },
            "moduleConfig": {
                "qna-openai": {
                    "frequencyPenalty": 0,
                    "maxTokens": 16,
                    "model": "text-davinci-002",
                    "presencePenalty": 0,
                    "temperature": 0,
                    "topP": 1
                },
                "text2vec-openai": {
                    "baseURL": "https://api.openai.com",
                    "model": "ada",
                    "modelVersion": "002",
                    "type": "text",
                    "vectorizeClassName": true
                }
            },
            "multiTenancyConfig": {
                "enabled": false
            },
            "properties": [
                {
                    "dataType": [
                        "text"
                    ],
                    "indexFilterable": true,
                    "indexSearchable": true,
                    "moduleConfig": {
                        "text2vec-openai": {
                            "skip": false,
                            "vectorizePropertyName": false
                        }
                    },
                    "name": "teamName",
                    "tokenization": "word"
                },
                {
                    "dataType": [
                        "text"
                    ],
                    "indexFilterable": true,
                    "indexSearchable": true,
                    "moduleConfig": {
                        "text2vec-openai": {
                            "skip": false,
                            "vectorizePropertyName": false
                        }
                    },
                    "name": "memberName",
                    "tokenization": "word"
                },
                {
                    "dataType": [
                        "text"
                    ],
                    "indexFilterable": true,
                    "indexSearchable": true,
                    "moduleConfig": {
                        "text2vec-openai": {
                            "skip": false,
                            "vectorizePropertyName": false
                        }
                    },
                    "name": "jobDescription",
                    "tokenization": "word"
                },
                {
                    "dataType": [
                        "text"
                    ],
                    "indexFilterable": true,
                    "indexSearchable": true,
                    "moduleConfig": {
                        "text2vec-openai": {
                            "skip": false,
                            "vectorizePropertyName": false
                        }
                    },
                    "name": "responsibilities",
                    "tokenization": "word"
                },
                {
                    "dataType": [
                        "text"
                    ],
                    "indexFilterable": true,
                    "indexSearchable": true,
                    "moduleConfig": {
                        "text2vec-openai": {
                            "skip": false,
                            "vectorizePropertyName": false
                        }
                    },
                    "name": "education",
                    "tokenization": "word"
                },
                {
                    "dataType": [
                        "text"
                    ],
                    "indexFilterable": true,
                    "indexSearchable": true,
                    "moduleConfig": {
                        "text2vec-openai": {
                            "skip": false,
                            "vectorizePropertyName": false
                        }
                    },
                    "name": "hobbies",
                    "tokenization": "word"
                }
            ],
            "replicationConfig": {
                "factor": 1
            },
            "shardingConfig": {
                "virtualPerPhysical": 128,
                "desiredCount": 1,
                "actualCount": 1,
                "desiredVirtualCount": 128,
                "actualVirtualCount": 128,
                "key": "_id",
                "strategy": "hash",
                "function": "murmur3"
            },
            "vectorIndexConfig": {
                "skip": false,
                "cleanupIntervalSeconds": 300,
                "maxConnections": 64,
                "efConstruction": 128,
                "ef": -1,
                "dynamicEfMin": 100,
                "dynamicEfMax": 500,
                "dynamicEfFactor": 8,
                "vectorCacheMaxObjects": 1000000000000,
                "flatSearchCutoff": 40000,
                "distance": "cosine",
                "pq": {
                    "enabled": false,
                    "bitCompression": false,
                    "segments": 0,
                    "centroids": 256,
                    "trainingLimit": 100000,
                    "encoder": {
                        "type": "kmeans",
                        "distribution": "log-normal"
                    }
                }
            },
            "vectorIndexType": "hnsw",
            "vectorizer": "text2vec-openai"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### objects

Then imported a list of members to the Weaviate instance.

```js
export async function teamMembersImport() {
  let batcher = client.batch.objectsBatcher();

  // When importing the teamsJson, or when the teamsJson becomes large,
  // implement batching system as per example on https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/quickstart#step-5-add-objects
  for (const team of teamsJson) {

    const memberObjects = team.members.map((teamMember) => ({
      class: 'TeamMember',
      properties: {
        teamName: team.teamName,
        memberName: teamMember.memberName,
        jobDescription: teamMember.jobDescription,
        responsibilities: teamMember.responsibilities,
        education: teamMember.education,
        hobbies: teamMember.hobbies,
      }
    }));

    batcher.withObjects(...memberObjects);
  }

  await batcher.do().then((batchResponse) => {
    batchResponse.map((weaviateObjectsGet) => {

      if (weaviateObjectsGet.result.status === 'FAILED') {
        console.log(weaviateObjectsGet.result.errors);
        return;
      }

      if (weaviateObjectsGet.result.status === 'SUCCESS') {
        console.log(`added teamMember ${weaviateObjectsGet.properties.memberName} to ${weaviateObjectsGet.class}`)
      }
    });
  });
}
```

A GET https://test-cluster-name.weaviate.network/v1/objects will produce the following response:

```json
{
    "deprecations": null,
    "objects": [
        {
            "class": "TeamMember",
            "creationTimeUnix": 1699264642221,
            "id": "0e479bb5-f2c8-4cc1-bc6d-06f298871356",
            "lastUpdateTimeUnix": 1699264642221,
            "properties": {
                "education": "Experienced software engineer.",
                "hobbies": "Dedicated marathon runner.",
                "jobDescription": "Lead Software Engineer",
                "memberName": "Mark Williams",
                "responsibilities": "Lead software development and ensure quality.",
                "teamName": "The Tech Innovators"
            },
            "vectorWeights": null
        },
        {
            "class": "TeamMember",
            "creationTimeUnix": 1699264642221,
            "id": "217de80d-13b5-4e7d-9757-b8c1c2502e39",
            "lastUpdateTimeUnix": 1699264642221,
            "properties": {
                "education": "Ph.D. in Engineering",
                "hobbies": "Avid hiker and explorer of national parks.",
                "jobDescription": "Senior Innovation Analyst",
                "memberName": "John Porter",
                "responsibilities": "Research emerging trends and technologies.",
                "teamName": "The Innovation Catalysts"
            },
            "vectorWeights": null
        },
        {
            "class": "TeamMember",
            "creationTimeUnix": 1699264642220,
            "id": "60fad861-24fc-4f91-949a-c34667251084",
            "lastUpdateTimeUnix": 1699264642220,
            "properties": {
                "education": "Market research professional.",
                "hobbies": "Self-taught guitarist and musician.",
                "jobDescription": "Market Research Analyst",
                "memberName": "Michael Lee",
                "responsibilities": "Gather and analyze market data for insights.",
                "teamName": "The Marketing Mavericks"
            },
            "vectorWeights": null
        },
        {
            "class": "TeamMember",
            "creationTimeUnix": 1699264642221,
            "id": "7ac2c278-79f8-4e39-bb74-6443c9e45ab6",
            "lastUpdateTimeUnix": 1699264642221,
            "properties": {
                "education": "Fluent in three languages, including Spanish.",
                "hobbies": "Amateur photographer and participates in local exhibitions.",
                "jobDescription": "Innovation Coordinator",
                "memberName": "Maria Rodriguez",
                "responsibilities": "Project management and execution.",
                "teamName": "The Innovation Catalysts"
            },
            "vectorWeights": null
        },
        {
            "class": "TeamMember",
            "creationTimeUnix": 1699264642220,
            "id": "8a3943f4-5f89-4e12-8b17-2fb9bd82f2d1",
            "lastUpdateTimeUnix": 1699264642220,
            "properties": {
                "education": "IT specialist with a passion for music.",
                "hobbies": "Skilled pianist and volunteer music instructor.",
                "jobDescription": "IT Support Specialist",
                "memberName": "Sarah Kim",
                "responsibilities": "Provide technical support and maintain IT infrastructure.",
                "teamName": "The Tech Innovators"
            },
            "vectorWeights": null
        },
        {
            "class": "TeamMember",
            "creationTimeUnix": 1699264642220,
            "id": "9d5afe43-4dc4-4985-b5bf-94685b5fe77e",
            "lastUpdateTimeUnix": 1699264642220,
            "properties": {
                "education": "Advocate for women in technology.",
                "hobbies": "Competitive chess player and marathon runner.",
                "jobDescription": "Chief Technology Officer (CTO)",
                "memberName": "Lisa Chen",
                "responsibilities": "Define technology strategy and oversee product development.",
                "teamName": "The Tech Innovators"
            },
            "vectorWeights": null
        },
        {
            "class": "TeamMember",
            "creationTimeUnix": 1699264642220,
            "id": "c918ef93-ad43-401d-a641-6dd5d9c670e8",
            "lastUpdateTimeUnix": 1699264642220,
            "properties": {
                "education": "Published author of a poetry book.",
                "hobbies": "Participates in open-mic events and believes in storytelling.",
                "jobDescription": "Content Manager",
                "memberName": "Emily Collins",
                "responsibilities": "Create and manage content for marketing channels.",
                "teamName": "The Marketing Mavericks"
            },
            "vectorWeights": null
        },
        {
            "class": "TeamMember",
            "creationTimeUnix": 1699264642220,
            "id": "eca76bea-3663-421a-918d-4e7d3bdea231",
            "lastUpdateTimeUnix": 1699264642220,
            "properties": {
                "education": "Marketing professional with years of experience.",
                "hobbies": "Mentors young professionals and coffee enthusiast.",
                "jobDescription": "Marketing Director",
                "memberName": "David Johnson",
                "responsibilities": "Develop and implement marketing strategy.",
                "teamName": "The Marketing Mavericks"
            },
            "vectorWeights": null
        },
        {
            "class": "TeamMember",
            "creationTimeUnix": 1699264642221,
            "id": "fed0db0d-2456-48a4-8aef-4c7307381a28",
            "lastUpdateTimeUnix": 1699264642221,
            "properties": {
                "education": "Master's degree in Business Administration",
                "hobbies": "Passionate about art and volunteers as a painting instructor.",
                "jobDescription": "Team Leader",
                "memberName": "Sarah Mitchell",
                "responsibilities": "Drive innovation and foster a culture of creativity.",
                "teamName": "The Innovation Catalysts"
            },
            "vectorWeights": null
        }
    ],
    "totalResults": 9
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you're not returning anything from the `question` function. You are indeed doing the call to Weaviate, but not returning anything.

Comment: Dang! That's it haha. Thank you 